# merge two multi dimensional arrays based on combination of elements from one array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays.  I want to add $inv_new to $inv_h where StoreNumber = org_number, SupplierNumber = supplier_number and InvoiceNumber = invoice_number
I have tried array_merge, but I can't determine how to match the keys in the two arrays so that the new elements are added where the "keys" match.

```
vdump($inv_new);
 array(1) {
   [0] => array(6) {
   'StoreNumber' → str•3 '11 '
   'SupplierNumber' → str•4 '6303'
   'InvoiceNumber' → str•11 'DI613718812'
   'ReasonCode' → str•4 'Dept'
   ["ReasonNote"] → NULL
   ["ResolutionCode"] → NULL
   }
 }
 vdump($inv_h);
 array(30) {
  ....
   [22] => array(5) {
   'org_id' → str•2 '11'
   'org_number' → str•2 '11'
   'supplier_number' → str•4 '6303'
   'supplier_name' → str•27 'BLAH'
   'invoice_number' → str•11 'DI613718812'
   }
```

would result in:

```
      array(30) {
  ....
   [22] => array(8) {
   'org_id' → str•2 '11'
   'org_number' → str•2 '11'
   'supplier_number' → str•4 '6303'
   'supplier_name' → str•27 'BLAH'
   'invoice_number' → str•11 'DI613718812'
   'ReasonCode' -> str 4 'Dept'
   ["ReasonNote"] -> NULL
   ["ResolutionCode"] -> NULL
   }
```

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10572576/292735 (I know it uses `array_merge`, but it removes duplicates before hand)

Comment: Will inv_new ever have multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use loops to match the corresponding elements and then use `array_merge()` on the elements to copy the fields.

```
foreach ($inv_new as $inv1) {
    foreach ($inv_h as &$inv2) {
        if ($inv1['StoreNumber'] == $inv2['org_id']
            && $inv1['SupplierNumber'] == $inv2['supplier_number']
            && $inv1['InvoiceNumber'] == $inv2['invoice_number']) {
            $inv2 = array_merge($inv1, $inv2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the purpose of "break" to end the looping once the first match is found? (there will only be one match because those fields are the key).  i just want to make sure i understand.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose. I assumed the matches would be unique. But I made a mistake, it should just be `break`, not `break 2`, to end the inner loop but continue the outer one.

Answer (score 1):

May be best in this case to just assign values manually, since there are different naming conventions used for keys and array_unique may prevent the multiple null values from being assigned.

```
//iterate over the main array
foreach ($inv_h as $hkey => $hval) {

  //build our if statement (nice and tidy)
  $store_match = ($hval['org_number'] == $inv_new[0]['StoreNumber']);
  $supplier_match = ($hval['supplier_number'] == $inv_new[0]['SupplierNumber']);
  $invoice_match = ($hval['invoice'] == $inv_new[0]['InvoiceNumber']);

  if ($store_match && $supplier_match && $invoice_match) {
    //assign array values manually
    //cant use array merge because we would end up with some duplicates
    //due to different naming conventions (org_number vs StoreNumber)
    $inv_h[$hkey]['ReasonCode'] = $inv_new[0]['ReasonCode'];
    $inv_h[$hkey]['ReasonNote'] = $inv_new[0]['ReasonNote'];
    $inv_h[$hkey]['ResolutionCode'] = $inv_new[0]['ResolutionCode'];

  }
}
```