# How to merge, combine associative array with sequential array in php?

Tags: php

How do I combine these two arrays into a single array say `$array3`?

```
$array1 =[1,2,3];
$array2=['a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3];
```

Comment: use `array_merge` You can try this one https://eval.in/791926

Comment: what is expected result ?

Comment: @SahilGulati thanks. it helped.

Comment: @Ben welcome.... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP merge arrays with only NOT DUPLICATED values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572546/php-merge-arrays-with-only-not-duplicated-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$temp = array_slice(array_keys($array1), 0, count($array2));

$array3 = array_merge($array1, array_combine($temp, $array2));
```

I believe this is what you're asking.