# How to get the array values from different arrays into a single using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array-like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1861
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1938
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1452
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1938
)
Array
(
    [0] => 21
)
```

This is a single array contain this array of elements.
I need the result like :

```
$arr = array(4,1861,1938,1452,21);
```

That means I need the only array unique values from these arrays. For this, I am using array_walk_recursive(), array_merge() etc. But I didn't get my results.

Answer (score 2):

Merge all the arrays and then call `array_unique()`.

```
$result = array_unique(array_merge(...$array));
```

`...$array` spreads the elements of the original array into arguments to `array_merge()`.

If you're using an old version of PHP before ellipsis, use `call_user_func_array()` instead.

```
$result = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));
```

Comment: I am using the  PHP 5.4 version. Is there any option with this version?

Comment: Use `call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array)` instead of using ellipsis.

Comment: I already tried this function.But I dint get the result.

Comment: Is there any problem with call_user_func_array in PHP 5.4 version? because I tried and found there is no result. And I just display my array values, I got my array values. After that, I used this function I dint get any results?

Comment: I just tried it in PHP 5.4 and it worked fine.

Comment: `$array = [[4, 1861], [4, 1938], [4, 1452], [4, 1938], [21]];
  $result = array_unique(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array));
print_r($result);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to use array_merge then array_unique

```
$array = array_unique (array_merge ($array1, $array2));
```

check this please https://stackoverflow.com/a/10572576/2429434

Comment: I have only one array. $array1. In array 1 contains different arrays with values.

Comment: They said the input is a single array, not multiple variables.

Comment: @Sonia in this case you use this  `$array = array_unique (array_merge (...$array1));
` check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17041344/2429434

Comment: I understood this method and I tried to this one, but my execution stops after this code